# What is the use of different OnBeforeRequestOptions and OnHeadersReceivedOptions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

From the [WebRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#types), I see there are multiple options available as

#### onBeforeRequestOptions

> Enum
> "blocking", or "requestBody"

#### OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions

> Enum
> "requestHeaders", or "blocking"

I understand We need to pass "blocking" when we need to modify the Request in blocking fashion.

My question is **When do we need the other options ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have read-only access to request body if you wish.

Same with request headers, and if you have blocking enabled as well you can modify them.

Passing those to your listener is an expensive operation, and that's why it's not on by default. You should not add them unless you need them.